# How to view value custom field community builder

Tags: php, joomla

i am using joomla 2.5 and install component community builder with work properly, and on the customize field i am add some field `cb_nip`, how to i get and show values `cb_nip` from `php` from user login, because i need values `cb_nip` for custom condition for me.

i tried get cb_nip values with script, but nothing shown anything :

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();        
$cb_nip = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->cb_nip);
echo $comprofiler->comprofiler['cb_nip'];
```

please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the database to do this.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = $this->getDbo();     
$query = 'SELECT cb_nip FROM #__comprofiler WHERE user_id='.$user->id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$cb_nip = $db->loadResult();

echo $cb_nip;
```